# How can I access the custom property （Visibility1）of a Dynamicblock in CAD

Tags: python, autocad

I have a project which need some blocks defined with different forms (visibility), I need to know coordinates. Numbers of those different visibility of each dynamicblock.

I had tried GetDynamicBlockProperties method via pyautocad, it returned:

```
<bound method GetDynamicBlockProperties of <POINTER(IAcadBlockReference) ptr=0xb861dd4 at c62f3d0>>
```

In the manual help of autodesk Active Xreference Guide, I find those:

```
GetDynamicBlockProperties Method (ActiveX)


Gets the properties of the dynamic block. 

Supported platforms: Windows only 

Signature
VBA: 

RetVal = object.GetDynamicBlockPropertiesobject 
Type: BlockReference, MInsertBlock 

The objects this method applies to. 

Return Value (RetVal)
Type: Variant (array of DynamicBlockReferenceProperty objects) 

Array of dynamic properties assigned to the block. 

Remarks
A collection of DynamicBlockReferenceProperty objects is returned only if the block reference is a dynamic block containing custom properties. 

Examples
VBA: 

Not availableVisual LISP: 

Not available
```

and my code is :

{

```
 for i in acad.iter_objects('BlockRef'):
        if i.IsDynamicBlock:
            print (i.EffectiveName)
            print(i.GetDynamicBlockProperties)
```

}

it returned :

'''
those names of each dynamicblock
<bound method GetDynamicBlockProperties of <POINTER(IAcadBlockReference) ptr=0xb35d23c at c01f6e8>>
'''

i have been stucked here for two days, can somebody help me to know what this return means and how to access the custom properties of a dynamicnlock, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the DynamicBlockProperties collection, something like this (not tested, I do not use Python):

```
 for i in acad.iter_objects('BlockRef'):
        if i.IsDynamicBlock:
            print (i.EffectiveName)
            for p in i.GetDynamicBlockProperties:
                print (p.PropertyName)
                print (p.Value)
```

Comment: Thank u for ur answering, i have just tried ur code. it turns like GetDynamicBlockProperties is a method and is not iterable.

Comment: may be this way: `for p in i.GetDynamicBlockProperties():`

Comment: HI, i have tried ur method,and it turns out like : for p in i.GetDynamicBlockProperties():
  File "C:\Users\oulingcheng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py", line 506, in __ctypes_from_outparam__
    result = self.value
  File "C:\Users\oulingcheng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py", line 457, in _get_value
    typ = _vartype_to_ctype[self.vt & ~VT_ARRAY]
KeyError: 9
>>>  after so much time im still stuck in this place when this occation happens to me again,lol.

Answer (score 0):

bro. Has solved this problem about `GetDynamicBlockProperties`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).